# Bazel equivalent of include what you use?

Tags: bazel

Is there a Bazel equivalent of [include what you use](https://include-what-you-use.org)? I'm looking for a tool that will eliminate false dependencies in a Bazel build by removing dependencies from `BUILD` files and checking if the project still builds.

Is there any reason this approach wouldn't work?

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/blob/master/unused_deps can do this for java_library. If you're looking for C++, maybe it's enough inspiration to build your own tool?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you do try and make your own tool. You might find [buildozer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/blob/master/buildozer/README.md) in conjunction with bazel query a good starting point.

Comment: C++: https://github.com/martis42/depend_on_what_you_use

Comment: Is there one for python?

Comment: It seems this is the tracker for python: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/issues/296

Comment: To which programming language is this question related?

Comment: This is for any programming language that bazel supports.